# Swift Spritekit - Slow X movement following finger drag

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am making a spritekit game where the player controls a boat by swiping their finger left and right. The boat stays stationary on the Y axis while barriers are moving towards it.

The player movement needs to be slow and following the X position of a dragging finger. The player needs to rotate in the direction of the player and slowly move towards it with a delay.

I have achieved this movement in Unity but I am remaking the game in spritekit and cannot replicate it.

I have attached a video where the movement is shown in action.

[Here is the video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qx6r03alnsu9tf2/Video%2006-03-2018%2C%2020%2050%2040.mov?dl=0).

If anyone has any idea on how to achieve this movement I would highly appreciate it :)

Comment: This is way too broad of a question. What have you tried, what doesn’t work about it? If you have a solution in Unity, why can you not just use the same algorithm?

Comment: Too broad but: look at physics body, apply angular impulse...

Comment: This site isn't set up to teach you how to use SpriteKit. You have to read the doc, practice some tutorials, get familiar with it, do some of your own experimentation. Then you will know what to do.